# Check if some specific function is present in the function definition PYTHON

Tags: python, function, parsing

I'd like to have a python function `functionpresent("functionName",f)` which returns `True` if the function called `functionName` is present in the function definition of `f` and `False` otherwise.

I've tried a lot of thing but nothing is really helping me.

Comment: *present in the function definition*, well present in which function's definition?

Comment: to awini-haudhary : Yes i changed my post the function i need is functionpresent("functionName',f). I didn't do a lot of programming in python sorry. I'm developping a C++ software but i need to use python in some part of my program and i need to do some python checking before returning the result to my C++ software

Comment: I think you want to know if the function "functionName" is called in the function f. Then you need to inspect f. "is present" is ambiguous. However you'd better tell what you want to do on top of that, I suspect there is a better way.

Comment: It is unclear what `f` is. Is it a class, function, or ?

Comment: f is a function and i want to know if the function named functionName may be called if i call f

Answer (score 4):

For that you can use [**`hasattr`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr):

#### Example

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def hello(self):
        pass

a = A()
>>> hasattr(a, 'hello')
True

>>> hasattr(a, 'bye')
False
```

Comment: here's and example --> def hello : print("hello") /////the function i need is like this functionPresent("print",hello) returns true

Comment: @Downvoter, Anything wrong with my answer? Please let me know so that I can improve it. Thank you

Comment: the function i need is like this functionPresent("print",hello) returns true because the function hello uses the function print

Comment: @user3516044, I am currently trying to figure it out. Sorry. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Hi what do you think about :
co=f.func_code
li=co.co_names
if functionName in li :
     return True

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need something like this:

```
def functionPresent(name):
    return name in globals() and callable(globals()[name])
```

Comment: Sorry i also need the function i want to check like this functionPresent(name,f). It checks wheter the function named "name" is present in function f

Comment: Not necessarly called because we can have an if statement and then the function won't be called